# do_action doesn't trigger if it's in a template that gets loaded via REST endpoint

Tags: actions, rest-api, get-template-part

i'm building a single page application using woocommerce and custom REST endpoints to get template parts and load them into the browser ... one endpoint is getting `content-single-product.php` template which loads single product details below is the code of the template

```
<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

and here is the code that get's the product template and send back to javascript

```
/**
* Get Single Product
*
* @param int $product_id product id
* @return string|boolean html for single page
*/
function nh_get_product( $product_id ) {
    global $product;
    $output_html;

    ob_start();
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    get_template_part('woocommerce/content-single-product');
    $output_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output_html;

}


public function get_item( $request ) {
    $product_id = $request->get_param('p_id');

    if ( function_exists( 'nh_get_product' ) && $product_id ) {
      $output_html = nh_get_product( $product_id );
      if ( !empty($output_html) ) {
        $data = array( 'result' =>  $output_html );
        return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
      }
    }

    return new WP_Error( 'not-found', 'cannot find product', array( 'status' => 500 ) );
  }
```

the endpoint is working fine and sending back the html to the javascript, the problem is in `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );` it does not trigger and does not throw any errors ... i replaced it with basic action hook that echo 'test' just for testing and still did not trigger .. im guessing do_action does not work inside `ob_start();`

i could just replace the do_action with direct calls to whatever the hook was doing and it will work i'm guessing ... but i just wanted to keep consistent with woocommerce templating system so i avoid any future big conflicts with the updates

EDIT: i removed the part of the HTML content in `content-single-product.php` that runs fine to ease in reading my question

Comment: 80 lines of HTML markup to help you? Please shorten your question and check the spelling.

Comment: @MaxYudin i included the code that runs the whole logic to provide enough information for anyone helping ... i could remove `<section id=product>` and leave `do_action` line only after all it's what my question is about .. just thought to put the whole template maybe it will help